# Can I host a Camel Context directly on an ActiveMQ instance?

Tags: activemq-classic

In other words, does ActiveMQ have Camel built in, and can I configure routing and handlers directly on the ActiveMQ process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see: [This easily findable documentation page (Google is your friend).](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)

Comment: Silly StackExchange sites (or silly me), I posted this on StackOverflow, found the answer a few seconds later and then could not find my question on StackExchange (instead of StackOverflow), and then assumed something went wrong with the post. Yes, Google is my friend.